# How to match two stereo images without camera information

Tags: image, image-processing, opencv, python

I am trying to use OpenCV in Python and I'm given two stereoscopic images; however, I am not given any information regarding the camera i.e. focal lengths. That means I **can't use the openCV calibrate** method as they are old images taken before I was even born!

The photos are nearly identical except one is shifted slightly horizontally and vertically. What I basically need to do is to take the left image and shift it translationally to match the right image.

How would I go about doing this?

I know you can translate images by inputing however much pixels you want to shift from reading [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/image-translation-using-opencv-python/).

But I need this function to work for any images that needs translations. Currently I'm thinking of creating a left and right matrix that has a 5x5 pixel chunk sums of its RGB values inside of the 5x5 pixel chunk and compare it to the right and see how many pixels it's deviated by horizontally and vertically. But I have major doubts about this solution

The end goal is so that it'll create perfectly aligned stereoscopic images. If I overlay the two images on top of each other, **they should be perfectly aligned vertically.**

Comment: a few examples (pictures) would be nice.